# React Native - "Payload is set and no content-type header specified" error on android

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest, content-type

github issue: https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-stanza-demo/issues/1

[this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bc74dd1e14372ce2ff7c6d21401e67c946eb7595/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/NetworkingModule.java#L241) line:241, there is a "payload is set and no content-type header specified" blocking for android. But not for iOS.

simple android:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (request.readyState !== 4) {
    return;
  }

  if (request.status === 200) {
    console.log('success', request.responseText);
  } else {
    console.warn('error');
  }
};

request.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/http-bind/');
request.send('<body hold="1" rid="9211032549" to="www.example.com" ver="1.6" wait="30" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind" xmlns:xmpp="urn:xmpp:xbosh" xmpp:version="1.0"></body>');
```

request: error,

error: **payload is set but no content-type header specified**

But ios working,

request: 200 (success)

success: data

**Is this something that react-native needs to fix?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to set the content-type explicitly before calling your `.send()` method e.g.

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
```

It worked for me in a similar situation.